# Confusion about exec maven plugin?What is the purpose of arguments tag

Tags: java, maven, plugins, configuration, exec

I am new to using maven(forgive me if the question seems idiotic) and I am trying to use the maven exec plugin to run my project after it has been packaged as a jar but I am confused about the goals and arguments tags which are needed in the pom.xml inside the plugin tag

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
   <executions>><!-- what does this tag specify,nearly everything in it is un-understood to me-->

    <execution>
     <phase>test</phase>
     <goals>
      <goal>java</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
      <mainClass>my.company.name.packageName.TestMain</mainClass><!-- i understand its the path of my class which has the main method -->
      <arguments><!-- what does this tell to the maven or the plugin ?-->
       <argument>myArg1</argument>
       <argument>myArg2</argument><!-- are these arguments passed to my main method in the args array?-->

      </arguments>
     </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
```

what is the arguments tag doing?What does it specify?Does it provide String args array to the main method or what?I m so confused please help

Answer (score 0):

These are the arguments which we pass to the main method of a java program.

This plugin basically helps to execute a java program.

Please read the link for more information

http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/